# How to put conditional for a iterator?

Tags: conditional

I have the next code:

```
f = Table[
mtxt[[p[[i, j]] - wi ;; p[[i, j]] + we]], {i, n}, {j, m}]
```

I want that wi and we have different values depend of the j value. For example, if j=1 then we=20 and wi=10, if j=2 then we=12 and wi=5, etc... I tried with If but don´t work. How can I do it?

Comment: Is there a pattern relating `we` and `wi` to `j` or are they just arbitrary numbers?

Comment: How about making we and wi m-length vectors indexed by j?

Comment: How about `Piecewise` ?

Comment: @ChrisK, there is not pattern relating between we, wi and j. They are arbitrary numbers.

Comment: I don't understand how to make we and wi vectors indexed by j. On the other hand, I tried with Piecewise but not work:    wi = Piecewise[{{10, j = 1}, {5, j = 2}}]    .

Comment: At the very least, your `Piecewise` function will need to use `==` instead of `=` when testing for equality; i.e., `Piecewise[{{10, j == 1}, {5, j == 2}}]`.

Comment: That error!!. Thanks @user21382.